# Sonata Admin many to many with attributes form

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I'm using 4 entites :

1. translator
2. language
3. translator_language
4. site

Translator can have many languages.
Languages can have many translators.
A site can be assigned a couple translator/language.

So I have been forced to create translator_language even if there is no "real attribute" inside.

```
class Language {

/**
 * @var \XX\TranslateBundle\Entity\TranslatorLanguage
 * 
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="TranslatorLanguage", mappedBy="language")
 */
private $translators;
```

xx

```
class Translator {
/**
     * @var XX\TranslateBundle\Entity\TranslatorLanguage
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="TranslatorLanguage", mappedBy="translator")
     */
    private $languages;
```

xx

```
class TranslatorLanguage
{

    /**
     * @var XX\TranslateBundle\Entity\Translator
     *  
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Translator", inversedBy="languages")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="translatorID", referencedColumnName="ID", nullable=false)
     */
    private $translator;

    /**
     * @var XX\TranslateBundle\Entity\Language
     *  
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Language", inversedBy="translators")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="languageID", referencedColumnName="ID", nullable=false)
     */
    private $language;


    /**
     * @var XX\TranslateBundle\Entity\TranslatorSite
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="TranslatorSite", mappedBy="translatorLanguage")
     */
    private $translatorSites;
```

Mapping is ok ([Mapping]  OK - The mapping files are correct.)

With ManyToMany mapping, I could do

```
$formMapper->add('languages', null,
                        array('required' => false, 'expanded' => true))
```

in TranslatorAdmin.php, and that would render checkboxes for each languages, and checked one for languages associated to translator, now I'm trying to get that with my new architecture, but no way I manage to do that easily.

I don't really want to create a translatorlanguageAdmin because I don't want the form to be the same, coming from translator or language (as it can be done with simple many to many mapping)

Do I need to associate a query and a template to the showMapper ? Or am I missing something easy?

Comment: general question: why dont you create a many-to-many relationship between language and translator and add the sites to your translator?

Comment: Because that wouldn't mean the same thing I guess, I want to associate associations of translator/language to a site, not a translator with all his languages.

Comment: then you should create many-to-many between translator -> language and side and translator -> language. a translator can have languages he is able or allowed to translate, a site can have different languages and different translators .. there is no need for the fourth entity translatorSite, just makes things more complicated :)

Comment: I'm using a legacy DB, so I don't have a choice, but I agree with you on the fact that's not the perfect architecture. The problem is that I don't know if it's possible and how (if it is), to link a relation which is not an entity.

Comment: please phrase a correct question - i can't understand what you really want :) Like how can i create a form with the following features using sonata admin ...

Comment: My relation, translator-language, is ManyToMany without attribute. My relation, site/translator-language, is ManyToMany as well. But that's not possible (with doctrine mapping and my knowledge) to link an entity (site) with a relation between two entities (translator-language). So what is the workaround to achieve those relations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a very good and clear post about this subject, hope this will help a lot as it helped me:
http://www.prowebdev.us/2012/07/symfnoy2-many-to-many-relation-with.html